# How to get Contact records using apex:repeat tag in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, controller

Using `apex:repeat` Tag how to get All Contact Records in visualforce page .I have to achieve this without using `apex:pageBlockTable` and Standard Set Controller..

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with with standardController with `recordSetVar` as below.

*As per Salesforce documentation:*

Using a standard list controller is very similar to using a standard controller. First you set the `standardController` attribute on the `<apex:page>` component, then you set the `recordSetVar` attribute on the same component.

The `recordSetVar` attribute not only indicates that the page uses a list controller, it can indicates the variable name of the record collection. This variable can be used to access data in the record collection.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="contacts">
    <ol>
        <apex:repeat var="c" value="{!contacts}">
            <li>
                {!c.name}
            </li>
        </apex:repeat>
    </ol>
</apex:page>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_associate.htm

Comment: He said without using Standard Set Controller..